# React JS - Proxy event?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React and I'm using Semantic-ui-react. I'm trying to use the Dropdown.

When I want to get my value from the dropdown and call my function. My event get some proxy object.

```
  handleTagChange(e) {
    console.log("handleTagChange");
    console.log(e);
  }
```

But if I add something else like test in the function, the e.target.value works and test is the proxy object. Why is that?

```
  handleTagChange(test, e) {
    console.log("handleTagChange");
    console.log(test);
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All event handlers that `semantic-ui-react` components implement return the React Synthetic Event as the first argument (as vanilla React would) and component props + relevant state as the second argument.

Using your example:

```
handleTagChange(e, data) {
  console.log("handleTagChange");
  console.log(e); // React Synthetic Event
  console.log(data.name); // `name` prop
  console.log(data.value); // `value` that was just selected
}
```

---

Issue formalizing this change: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/623

Explanation of the rationale behind this from the discussion here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/638

> The `event.target` is a browser event property.  However, many
>   Semantic UI components, such as a Dropdown, Checkbox, and Radio do not
>   work directly with native browser form controls such as `input` and
>   `select`.  They are built using stylized markup and custom internal
>   state.
>
> Because of this, there are no native browser events available for
>   certain callbacks.  This is why all change events in Semantic-UI-React
>   provide the event first (when available) but also a second argument
>   which contains the data you need.  You should never have to access the
>   native browser event for most tasks.